# Javascript Rebinding An Bound Founction

Tags: javascript

Say I have the snippet

```
function hi() {
    console.log('Hello ' + this._hi);
}

var marcie = hi.bind({_hi: 'Sir'});
var patty = marcie.bind({_hi: 'Lucille'});

marcie(); // output: Hello Sir
patty(); // expected: Hello Lucille // actual: Hello Sir
```

I wanted to rebind the bound function **marcie** but it looks like rebinding it does not work.

I am aware of **call**, **apply** and **bind** in changing the function context. But it doesn't seem to work when it is already binded.

How can I rebind a bound function in javascript? 
Or is it not allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `bind`, you get a new function which is some kind of proxy: when you call that proxy, it ignores the passed `this` and calls the original function with the bound `this`.

Therefore:

- `hi` does something with `this`
- `marcie` ignores its `this` and calls `hi` with `{_hi: 'Sir'}` as the `this`
- `patty` ignores its `this` and calls `marcie` with `{_hi: 'Lucille'}` as the `this`

However, since `marcie` ignores `this`, `patty` is useless.

Instead, you should use `bind` always on the original function:

```
function hi() {
  return 'Hello ' + this._hi;
}
var marcie = hi.bind({_hi: 'Sir'}),
    patty = hi.bind({_hi: 'Lucille'});
[marcie(), patty()]; // ["Hello Sir", "Hello Lucille"]
```

- `hi` does something with `this`
- `marcie` ignores its `this` and calls `hi` with `{_hi: 'Sir'}` as the `this`
- `patty` ignores its `this` and calls `hi` with `{_hi: 'Lucille'}` as the `this`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you provide a link or source or documentation on this behavior? So I take it that there is no work around for this?

Comment: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FFunction%2Fbind) Looks like the books I've read forgot to mention this. Thanks again, gotta rethink the architecture. @Oriol

Comment: You can also see [`Function.prototype.bind`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5) in the spec, and the internal [\[\[Call\]\]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5.1) method of the returned function.